# Scala - iterators and takeWhile

Tags: scala, iterator

I am running the following piece of code:

```
 val it = List(1,1,1,2,2,3,3).iterator.buffered
 val compare = it.head
it.takeWhile(_ == compare).toList
```

and it returns (1,1,1). However, if I run this as:

```
val it = List(1,1,1,2,2,3,3).iterator.buffered
it.takeWhile(_ == it.head).toList
```

I am getting (1,1). Why is this the case? Isn't `head` evaluated upon calling `takeWhile` and the result should be the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the iterator is mutable, the value of `it.head` depends on when it is evaluated.

Inspecting the [implementation of `takeWhile`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L505) reveals that it removes the head of the iterator *before* applying the predicate.

So, on the third iteration, `it.head` evaluated from within the predicate will be `2`, because the third element has already been removed.

This is an illustration of why you should prefer immutability. It rules out a whole class of non-obvious behaviour like this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Ben James answer above. Below is `takeWhile` method code (credits: ben):

```
def hasNext = hdDefined || tail.hasNext && {
  hd = tail.next() //line 2
  if (p(hd)) hdDefined = true
  else tail = Iterator.empty
  hdDefined
}
```

In the third iteration after line 2, the value is: `hd=1` and remaining Iterator is `List(2,2,3,3)`. on calling `p(hd)`, it checks the iterator's `head` which in this case is `2`. Hence it breaks.