# Position of toList on Scala iterator changes output strangely

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator, breeze, scala-breeze

I am writing an iterative optimization algorithm in Scala. The function UpdateBG inputs a 2-tuple and outputs an updated 2-tuple. I establish an iterator to apply this update as many times as required until convergence (when the relative change in the objective falls below a tolerance).
The problem I have is the following. Consider the two lines of code

```
val altiterates=(Iterator.iterate((Binit,Ginit)) {x=> UpdateBG(x._1,x._2)}).sliding(2).take(5).toList.map(x => !Converged(x))
val iterates=(Iterator.iterate((Binit,Ginit)) {x=> UpdateBG(x._1,x._2)}).sliding(2).takeWhile(x => !Converged(x)).toList
```

The output of which is:
[image]

From the first line of code it is true that the iterates have not converged until iteration 5, so one would expect the second line of code which takes while convergence has not been satisfied to yield 4 new iterates, yet instead it is an empty list.

Why does the second line of code result in an empty list?

EDIT: CLUE

```
val foo1=(Iterator.iterate((Binit,Ginit)) {x=> UpdateBG(x._1,x._2)}).sliding(2).take(5).map(x => !Converged(x)).toList
val foo2=(Iterator.iterate((Binit,Ginit)) {x=> UpdateBG(x._1,x._2)}).sliding(2).take(5).toList.map(x => !Converged(x))
```

The only difference in foo1 and foo2 is where the toList is implemented, I wouldn't have thought it does, but the output is the opposite...

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please give a minimal runnable example that produces your error, so we can reproduce it. (You might even find your error while creating that example :) )

Comment: added a clue, I cannot make sense of this

Comment: Maybe this will explain something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356897/scala-iterators-and-takewhile

Comment: I have rewritten everything replacing iterators with streams and now it works perfectly. I will avoid iterators in the future and always go for streams.

Comment: @Lindon Be careful doing that. Streams store all their computed elements, so you might blow up memory use if you're not using it correctly. But usually you will be fine though.